# Password authentication failed while using two database in Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I have laravel app that run with two database. database_1 in local server, and database_2 in live server.

When I tried to get data from database 2, I get password authentication error

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" FATAL: password
authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

There is my .env config

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=infinite-mob
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=password

DB_CONNECTION_2=pgsql
DB_HOST_2=host
DB_PORT_2=5432
DB_DATABASE_2=infinite
DB_USERNAME_2=user
DB_PASSWORD_2=password
```

And database config

```
'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'infinite-mob'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'postgres'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

    'pgsql2' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', 'host'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'infinite'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model did you add this?

```
protected $connection = 'pgsql2';
```

And in pgsql2 your username and password is wrong, must be;

```
'pgsql2' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', '35.185.179.247'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'infinite'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'ics_mobile'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', 'password'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ]
```

Comment: That's it. the problem is in config. i am not careful enough. Thanks!